# CustomValidator ServerValidate event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to check if the email already exists in the database or not but somehow the event doesn't seem to fire at all
I want that when someone enters email id in the textbox and when it goes out focus the servervalidate event should trigger and validate the email entered

Aspx Code (customvalidator id="cv3")

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="bs-container">
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label class="control-label">Name:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="name" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" required="true" runat="server" autofocus="true" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="vendor_cpass" ValidationGroup="vg1" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label class="control-label">Email:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="vendor_email" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control" CausesValidation="true" placeholder="e.g. me@mymail.com" required="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="vendor_email" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" ErrorMessage="Already Exists" ValidationGroup="vg2" OnServerValidate="cv3_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="vendor_email" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="vg2" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="vendor_email" ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="vg2" ValidationExpression="^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" Display = "Dynamic" ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address" SetFocusOnError="true"/>

        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label class="control-label">Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="vendor_pass" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Password" CausesValidation="true" required="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg3" ControlToValidate="vendor_pass" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg3" ControlToValidate="vendor_pass" ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Minimum 8 characters atleast 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label class="control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="vendor_cpass" TextMode="Password"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg4" ControlToValidate="vendor_cpass" ClientValidationFunction="cp_check" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="" SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg4" ControlToValidate="vendor_cpass" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label class="control-label">Mobile No:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="vendor_mobile" TextMode="Phone" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 9999999999" required="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv5" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg5" ControlToValidate="vendor_mobile" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg5" ControlToValidate="vendor_mobile" ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationExpression="^\d{10}$" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Should be 10 digits" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label>Address</label>
            <br />
            <label class="control-label">Street Address:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="street" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 7th Avenue Street" required="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv6" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg6" ControlToValidate="street" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <label class="control-label">City:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="city" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. Kolkata" required="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv7" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg6" ControlToValidate="city" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <label class="control-label">State:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="state" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. West Bengal" required="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv8" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg6" ControlToValidate="state" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <label class="control-label">Pincode:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="pincode" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. 700700" required="true" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv9" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg6" ControlToValidate="pincode" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg6" ControlToValidate="pincode" ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationExpression="^\d{6}$" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Should be 6 digits" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <label>Criteria for email notification</label>
            <br />
            <label>Estimated cost of project</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ecp" CssClass="form-control">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--Any Amount--" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1 Lakh and Above" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="5 Lakhs and Above" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10 Lakhs and Above" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="50 Lakhs and Above" Value="50"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1 Crore and Above" Value="100"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="5 Crores and Above" Value="500"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="10 Crores and Above" Value="1000"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="50 Crores and Above" Value="5000"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <label class="control-label">Please Select the Subjects for which Tender notices you are Interested</label>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="main_check" Checked="true" Text="Notify me for all tenders" runat="server" Onclick="main_check_changed(this)" />
            <br />
            <label>Goods</label>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="goods" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            <br />
            <label>Services</label>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="services" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline required">
            <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="81px" OnClick="submit_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="reset" runat="server" Text="Reset" Width="81px" OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

C# code: (method cv3_ServerValidate)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Tender
{
    public partial class vendor_reg : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        string v_id;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from goods");
                cmd.Connection = con;
                MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                goods.DataSource = sdr;
                goods.DataTextField = "title";
                goods.DataValueField = "goods_id";
                goods.DataBind();
                for (int i = 0; i < goods.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    goods.Items[i].Selected = true;
                    goods.Items[i].Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkedchanged(this)");
                }
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("select * from services");
                cmd1.Connection = con;
                MySqlDataReader sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                services.DataSource = sdr1;
                services.DataTextField = "title";
                services.DataValueField = "service_id";
                services.DataBind();
                for (int i = 0; i < services.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    services.Items[i].Selected = true;
                    services.Items[i].Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkedchanged(this)");
                }
            }

        }
        public void MsgBox(String ex, Page pg, Object obj)
        {
            string s = "<SCRIPT language='javascript'>alert('" + ex.Replace("\r\n", "\\n").Replace("'", "") + "'); </SCRIPT>";
            Type cstype = obj.GetType();
            ClientScriptManager cs = pg.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, s, s.ToString());
        }

        protected void cv3_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            MsgBox("! your message !", this.Page, this);
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select vendor_id from vendor where vendor_email=@email;");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", vendor_email.Text);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                cv3.ErrorMessage = "Email already exists in our database.Please check or try to login";
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into vendor (vendor_email,vendor_pass,vendor_name,vendor_addr,vendor_phone,vendor_ecp) values(@email, Aes_Encrypt(@pass,@email), @name, @addr, @phone, @ecp)", con);
            String addr = street.Text + ", " + city.Text + ", " + state.Text + ", " + pincode.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", vendor_email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", vendor_pass.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr", addr);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", vendor_mobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ecp", ecp.SelectedValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("select vendor_id from vendor where vendor_email=@email;");
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", vendor_email.Text);
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr1.Read()) {
                v_id = sdr1[0].ToString();
            }

            cmd1.Dispose();
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("insert into vendor_goods (vendor_id,goods_id) values(@v_id, @g_id)", con);
            MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand("insert into vendor_services (vendor_id,service_id) values(@v_id, @s_id)", con);
            for(int i = 0; i < goods.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (goods.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v_id", v_id);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_id", goods.Items[i].Value);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < services.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (services.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    cmd3.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v_id", v_id);
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id", services.Items[i].Value);
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("vendor_login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try changing <asp:Button ID="submit" to <asp:Button ID="mysubmit" or anything else that is not "submit" ? On my machine the code fails with "theForm.submit() is not a function" on the client side because submit is this input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

You need to change a few things here,

Add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your vendor_email textbox

Add `OnTextChanged="vendor_email_TextChanged"` to your vendor_email textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="vendor_email" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control" 
    OnTextChanged="vendor_email_TextChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true"
    placeholder="e.g. me@mymail.com" required="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Implement the event handler in the code behind and call Validate() (Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.validate?view=netframework-4.8))

```
protected void vendor_email_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
}
```

And finally,

Change the name of your submit button to something else because it overwrites the submit() method of the form

```
<asp:Button ID="submit2" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="81px" OnClick="submit_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks it worked so the Page.Validate("vg2"); was key command .